# ~ sign function in lukasiewicz logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In the book, "Soft Computing and its Applications in Business and Economics", by R. R. Aliev and Rafig Aliyev, what does the tilde sign mean in the following equation?

$$(\sim (P ≈ \Rightarrow Q))$$

I know how to solve inside, but couldn't find the function of the tilde.

Comment: It would help to have more context. What symbol is used for negation in your text?

Comment: @AlDante with this ¬ and there is no information about tilde in the book, that's why I am a bit confused

Comment: Can you post the book title? Tilde is used for negation in other texts, e.g. here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lukasiewicz/polish-notation.html

Comment: it's called "soft computing and its applications". then I assume they forgot to mention the tilde in the book

Comment: then it means that I should calculate the inside first, then take the negation of it as an answer?

Comment: If it's negation, then yes. See if the result makes sense.

It's the book by Kumar Ray?

Comment: no its by R. R. Aliev and Rafig Aliyev

Comment: @AlDante i got 0.7 as a result. makes sense. thank You for your time, I appreciate it!

Comment: OK, I'll add an answer and you can accept it.

Comment: In the version of the text "Soft Computing and its Applications in Business and Economics" by Professor Rafik Aziz Aliev, Professor Bijan Fazlollahi, Professor Rashad Rafik Aliev (auth.) they list tilde as negation on page 219.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tilde is used for negation in other texts, e.g. here: [plato.stanford.edu/entries/lukasiewicz/polish-notation.html](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lukasiewicz/polish-notation.html)

It is also listed as a negation operator on page 219 of the cited text.